# HTML tidy output option not working

Tags: htmltidy

The command line output option in HTML tidy does not work.  I run "tidy" in a command line window.  The code runs and outputs formatted HTML code to the screen then, stops (hangs) at the  line and does not go further.

```
tidy infile -o outfile
```

Output:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the only way I can get an output file is `tidy infile > outfile`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

contrary to the documentation, the correct sequence of commands is `tidy -o outfile infile`   all command switches must PRECEDE the infile name.

```
    `tidy infile -o outfile` -- wrong format
    `tidy -o outfile infile` -- correct format
```